# Is there a std::string equivalent for CString::Mid()?

Tags: c++, c-strings, stdstring

Is there any equivalent function in `std::string` for [`CString::mid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2019#mid)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent would be [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) with the following interface:

```cpp
basic_string substr( size_type pos = 0, size_type count = npos ) const;
constexpr basic_string substr( size_type pos = 0, size_type count = npos ) const;
```

And you can use it like:

```cpp
std::string str = "0123456789abcdefghij";

// returns [pos, size())
std::string sub1 = str.substr(10);
std::cout << sub1 << '\n';

// returns [pos, pos+count)
std::string sub2 = str.substr(5, 3);
```